# Proof related to the least squares method

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, least-squares

I've seen this exercise in several statistics text, but how they get to the final formula is something that I don't quite get. How do two squared terms suddenly become a binomial term? I've been trying to figure out how to get to the final formula but I don't get anywhere near. Hope you can help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One may recall that
$$
\bar{x}=\frac1N\cdot \sum_{n=1}^Nx_n
$$ giving
$$
\begin{align}
N^2\cdot \frac1N\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n-\bar{x})^2&=N\sum_{n=1}^N(x_n^2-2x_n\cdot\bar{x}+\bar{x}^2)
\\\\&=N\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2-2\:N\cdot\bar{x}\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n+N\cdot N\cdot \bar{x}^2
\\\\&=N\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2-2\:\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n\right)^2+\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n\right)^2
\\\\&=N\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2-\left(\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n\right)^2
\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n^2\cdot\sum_{n=1}^N1-\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n \cdot \sum_{n=1}^Nx_n
\\\\&=\det M
\end{align}
$$ as announced.

Comment: @Diego Are you Ok with my answer above? Or would you like me to elaborate on some points? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand this why you multiply  $$N\cdot N\cdot \bar{x}^{2}$$ . I mean in the equation I only see an N previous to that. Even so, this doesn't seem correct to me $$det M = N\sum x_{n}^{2} - (N\bar{x})^{2}$$ becuase as I understand in order to use the definition of $\bar{x}$. We would need to multiply by 1 or $$N/N$$ so we would get  $$det M = \frac{N^{2}}{N^{2}}\sum x_{n}^{2} - \frac{N^{2}}{N^{2}}\sum x_{n}\cdot \sum x_{n} $$

Comment: @Diego It's because we have from the first line, by expanding, $N\sum_{n=1}^N\bar{x}^2$ which is $N\cdot N\cdot \bar{x}^{2}$, since $\bar{x}$ is a constant with respect to $n$ and they are $N$ terms.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver now it's more clear what you meant. I forgot how the series of a constant work.

Comment: @Diego You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rl} n \|\mathrm x - \bar{x} \, 1_n\|_2^2 &= n (\mathrm x^T \mathrm x - 2 \bar{x} 1_n^T \mathrm x + n \bar{x}^2)\\\\ &= n (\mathrm x^T \mathrm x - 2 n \bar{x}^2 + n \bar{x}^2)\\\\ &= n (\mathrm x^T \mathrm x - n \bar{x}^2)\\\\ &= n \|\mathrm x\|_2^2 - (n \bar{x})^2\\\\ &= n \|\mathrm x\|_2^2 - (1_n^T \mathrm x)^2\end{array}$$